# Elasticsearch openssl

Tags: elasticsearch, ssl, openssl

I used openssl to generate self signed certs for elasticsearch, but I am unable to use this certs to start elasticsearch.

I keep getting the below error

```
[2023-07-16T19:42:22,649][ERROR][o.e.b.Elasticsearch      ] 
[MacBook-Pro.local] fatal exception while booting Elasticsearchorg.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSecurityException: failed to load SSL configuration [xpack.security.transport.ssl] - the truststore [/Users/mac/Documents/logging/elasticsearch/config/certs/transport.p12] does not contain any trusted certificate entries
    at org.elasticsearch.xcore@8.8.2/org.elasticsearch.xpack.core.ssl.SSLService.lambda$loadSslConfigurations$11(SSLService.java:617)
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1429)
    at java.base/java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap.forEach(Collections.java:1553)
    at org.elasticsearch.xcore@8.8.2/org.elasticsearch.xpack.core.ssl.SSLService.loadSslConfigurations(SSLService.java:613)
    at org.elasticsearch.xcore@8.8.2/org.elasticsearch.xpack.core.ssl.SSLService.<init>(SSLService.java:159)

See logs for more details.

ERROR: Elasticsearch did not exit normally - check the logs at /Users/mac/Documents/logging/elasticsearch/logs/playground-logging.log
```

I can't figure out the issue for the life of me.

These are the commands I used to generate the certs

```
openssl genrsa -out rootCA.key 2048
openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -key rootCA.key -sha256 -days 1024 -out rootCA.pem
openssl genrsa -out elasticsearch.key 2048
openssl req -new -key elasticsearch.key -out elasticsearch.csr -config openssl.cnf
openssl x509 -req -in elasticsearch.csr -CA rootCA.pem -CAkey rootCA.key -CAcreateserial -out elasticsearch.crt -days 500 -sha256 -extfile elasticsearch.cnf -extensions v3_req

openssl pkcs12 -export -out elasticsearch.p12 -inkey elasticsearch.key -in elasticsearch.crt -certfile rootCA.pem
openssl genrsa -out transport.key 2048
openssl req -new -key transport.key -out transport.csr -config openssl.cnf
openssl x509 -req -in transport.csr -CA rootCA.pem -CAkey rootCA.key -CAcreateserial -out transport.crt -days 500 -sha256 -extfile transport.cnf -extensions v3_req
openssl pkcs12 -export -out transport.p12 -inkey transport.key -in transport.crt -certfile rootCA.pem
```

And my elasticsearch.yml references the generated certs as shown below.

```
# Enable security features
xpack.security.enabled: true

xpack.security.enrollment.enabled: true

# Enable encryption for HTTP API client connections, such as Kibana, Logstash, and Agents
xpack.security.http.ssl:
  enabled: true
  keystore.path: certs/elasticsearch.p12

# Enable encryption and mutual authentication between cluster nodes
xpack.security.transport.ssl:
  enabled: true
  verification_mode: certificate
  keystore.path: certs/transport.p12
  truststore.path: certs/transport.p12
```

can someone please help me out, I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Difficult to put the finger on the exact problem, but you use the full p12 with private keys as trust store. What you can do instead is set the certificate authority to the root.pem directly according to this topic. https://discuss.elastic.co/t/the-truststore-does-not-contain-any-trusted-certificate-entries-after-upgrade-to-8-0/298338

Comment: @sleepyhead, yeah, I saw that, it works when I use `xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate_authorities` directly, but it isn't ideal, I don't think anyways, and I want to use the correct trustore.path

Comment: Try creating a p12 only with the rootca and call it trust store, you now have a private key in your truststore and you are reusing it as your keystore